# Dynamically replacing the content for large list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to render child elements of an element if the element is in view or removing the content if not in view like below on scroll event like below

```
    list.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.aBox');
        var toBe = counter - 1 - elements.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var inView = visibleY(elements[i]),
                ele = elements[i].querySelector('.item');
            if (inView === false && ele) {
                console.log("Not in visible, keeping it none");
                var height = elements[i].clientHeight;
                elements[i].style.height = height + "px";
                elements[i].innerHTML = "";
            } else if(!ele){
                console.log('Placing the content');
                var minArray = arr[toBe + 1 + i],
                    str = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < minArray.length; j++) {
                    str += "<div class='item'>" + minArray[j] + "</div>";
                }
                elements[i].innerHTML = str;
            }
        }
    });
```

It seems working but if I have a look at the DOM this is not working as expected. Someone please help me to find the problem, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxqbQ/42/).

**Update**

```
 function updateData(callback) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.aBox');
        elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
        var toBe = counter - 1 - elements.length;
        async.each(elements, function (element, cb) {
            var inView = $(element).is_on_screen(),
                ele = element.querySelector('.item');
            if (inView == false && ele) {
                console.log("Not in visible, keeping it none");
                var height = element.clientHeight;
                element.style.height = height + "px";
                element.innerHTML = "";
            } else if (!ele && inView) {
                console.log('Placing the content');
                var minArray = arr[toBe + 1 + i],
                    str = "";
                if (typeof minArray === "object") {
                    for (var j = 0; j < minArray.length; j++) {
                        str += "<div class='item'>" + minArray[j] + "</div>";
                    }
                    element.innerHTML = str;
                }
            }
            cb();
        }, function () {
            callback()
        });
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxqbQ/61/)

Comment: I have tried and it was working [but](http://jsfiddle.net/KxqbQ/61/) async js is breaking somewhere.

Comment: What is not working as expected? Please be more specific. Using `async` does not make any sense, as you have no asynchrony and are calling `cb()` synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: That doesn't describe your problem as well… and still uses `async` unnecessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have solved this problem. Posting here, so that it will be more helpful for people who want to work on mobiles to display very large lists with virtual scrolling

```
  var arr = new Array(10000);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = "Hello Dudes..." + i;
    }

    Array.prototype.chunk = function (chunkSize) {
        var array = this;
        return [].concat.apply([],
        array.map(function (elem, i) {
            return i % chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + chunkSize)];
        }));
    }

    arr = arr.chunk(50);

    var list = document.getElementById('longList');
    var button = document.getElementById('loadMore');

    var counter = arr.length,
        aBoxLen = 1;

    function appendBox() {
        var div = document.createElement('div'),
            str = "";
        div.className = "aBox";
        var minArray = arr[counter - aBoxLen];
        for (var i = 0; i < minArray.length; i++) {
            str += "<div class='item'>" + minArray[i] + "</div>";
        }
        div.innerHTML = str;
        div.setAttribute('index', counter - aBoxLen);
        var box = document.querySelector('.aBox');
        if (box) {
            list.insertBefore(div, box);
        } else {
            list.appendChild(div);
        }
        aBoxLen += 1;
    }

    appendBox();

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        appendBox();
    });

    $.fn.is_on_screen = function () {

        var win = $(window);

        var viewport = {
            top: win.scrollTop(),
            left: win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

    };




    function updateData(callback) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.aBox');
        elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
        var toBe = counter - 1 - elements.length;
        async.each(elements, function (element, cb) {
            var inView = $(element).is_on_screen(),
                ele = element.querySelector('.item');
            if (inView == false && ele) {
                console.log("Not in visible, keeping it none");
                var height = element.clientHeight;
                element.style.height = height + "px";
                element.innerHTML = "";
            } else if (!ele && inView) {
                console.log('Placing the content');
                console.log(element.getAttribute('index'));
                var minArray = arr[element.getAttribute('index')],
                    str = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < minArray.length; j++) {
                    str += "<div class='item'>" + minArray[j] + "</div>";
                }
                element.innerHTML = str;

            }
            cb();
        }, function () {
            // callback()
        });
    }


    var delay = false;
    var timeout = null;

    list.addEventListener('touchmove', function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            updateData();
        }
        }, delay);
    });
```

None of the solutions were specifically designed for mobiles, so I have implemented this.

**I think there is lots of space for improvement in this. If anybody want to improve it, please feel free to make it**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KxqbQ/70/)

Comment: What did you change to make it work? How does the solution work? Please describe it instead of just posting a large chunk of code

Comment: I used `var minArray = arr[toBe + 1 + i]`. Where i is undefined. Before I was using for loop and changed it to async each. That was the problem. And The code I was using to determine whether an element is in view or not was also the problem. Thanks.